# Group by One distinct And Another column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like the following :

```
CREATE TABLE mine_1 ([name] VARCHAR(255) , [BRAND] VARCHAR(255) , [RX] int)

INSERT INTO mine_1
    ([name],[BRAND], [RX])
VALUES
    ('2017','ABC',5),
    ('2017','def',15),
    ('2018','efg',8),
    ('2018','hij',9);
```

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e5367/14)

I want to group by by `name` and `Brand` and `sum(Rx)` and output should look like below,

```
('2017','ABC',20)
('2017','def',20)
('2018','efg',17)
('2018','hij',17)
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  This is pretty basic SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Join your query to the table:

```
select m.name, m.BRAND, g.RX 
FROM mine_1 m inner join (
  select name, SUM(RX) RX  
  FROM mine_1 
  group by name
) g on g.name = m.name
```

Comment: I have duplicate brand as well

Comment: Can u help on this

Comment: This code is an answer to the requirement as you posted it. If there is a different requirement post anew question with all the relevant data.

Comment: one slight change alone

Comment: Please help me on that @forpas